It is necessary to add dependencies to Maven BOM or only versions?
What is the right way to create maven BOM file? Should  it include only versions or dependencies are also required. I mean two variants of BOM:
Var #1:
<properties>
    <javafx.version>23</javafx.version>
</properties>
<!-- no dependencyManagement section -->

Var #2:
<properties>
    <javafx.version>23</javafx.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


Variant 1 only defines a property. There is no relation between that property and a dependency version unless you explicitly declare that, either in dependencyManagement of a BOM or the final POM, or dependencies of a POM.

@MarkRotteveel For example - I use BOM as a parent, and in child pom I do <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId><artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>           <version>${javafx.version}</version>

Then you're not using a BOM, you're just defining a property in a parent project and using that in a child project. A BOM by definition has a dependencyManagement section that defines dependencies and their versions, so projects importing that BOM don't need to specify the version element of their dependencies (or at least, for the dependencies defined in that BOM). That is basically all a BOM is, a definition of dependencies and their versions.

@MarkRotteveel Thank you for the explanation. I think you are right

Variant 1 will not work because properties are not imported from BOMs, only dependencyManagement.
So you need to use Variant 2.
